# How to change Accordion Collapse Direction in React Boostrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to change the direction of the way the accordion element in react-bootstrap moves. Currently it moves down. Is there a simple way to make it open  in the up direction?

Below is an example of one of my components. I want to be able to open it in the upwards direction as opposed to downward, the reason being that I have placed it on the bottom of the screen and so when I open it in default settings it goes down as opposed to up:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Accordion, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const InfoBox = ( props ) => {

    const Styles = {
        width: "100%",
        marginTop: "147%"
    }

    return (
        <div style={Styles}>
        <Accordion>
            <Card>
            <Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                    Link Info
                </Accordion.Toggle>
            </Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                <Card.Body>
                <div>{`Link Address: ${props.sa}`}</div>
                <div>{`community board: ${props.cb}`}</div>
                <div>{`lat: ${props.lat}`}</div>
                <div>{`lon: ${props.lon}`}</div>
                </Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>    
        </Accordion>
        </div>
    )
};

export default InfoBox;
```

Comment: Would putting the `Accordion.Collapse` component above the `Card.Header` component suffice?

Answer (score 8):

Moving the accordion upward can be achieved by simple CSS changes.

We can reverse the flex-direction of the div with classname `.card`.
By default the `flex-direction` is `column`. We can override it and make it `column-reverse`.

`.card` default styling provided by bootstrap

```
.card { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Change the flex direction by adding css styling in your projects with a higher precedence. Like this -

```
.my-footer .card {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Here is the codesandbox solution for the same - https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-fog-nxb6n?file=/src/styles.css

More explanation - When react-bootstrap renders the accordion, it adds this DOM structure -

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" style="">
      <div class="card-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By giving `flex-direction` as `column-reverse` we are interchanging the flow of `.card-header` and `.collapse` elements.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need any CSS changes or anything. What I did was simply moving the `<Accordion.Collapse>` above the `<Accordion.Toggle>` like so;

```
    <Accordion>
      <Card>
        <Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
             <div>{`Link Address: ${props.sa}`}</div>
             <div>{`community board: ${props.cb}`}</div>
             <div>{`lat: ${props.lat}`}</div>
             <div>{`lon: ${props.lon}`}</div>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              Link Info
            </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
      </Card>    
    </Accordion>
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible: a `Collapse` doesn't move, a `Collapse` just expands or (indeed) collapses.

The perceived effect when a `Collapse` expands is that what is beyond the `Collapse` itself moves down, but actually the page enlarges and keeps the vertical scroll at same position.

Since your `Collapse` is at the bottom of the page, a possible solution is to also scroll down the page simultaneously to the expansion of the `Collapse`.

You should achieve it quite easily *playing* with `window.scrollY` and `window.scrollTo()`.

Hope this helps.